# measurability of function of two variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

The question might be trivial, but I am confused.

Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ be the sets with some topologies $\mathcal{X}$, $\mathcal{Y}$ and $\mathcal{Z}$, respectively, defined on them. Let $f$ be the function $f: X \times Y \to Z$, such that $f(\cdot, y):X \to Z$ is measurable for any $y \in Y$ and $f(x, \cdot): Y \to Z$ is measurable for any $x \in X$, with respect to $\sigma$-algebras generated by the topologies.

The question: is function $f: X \times Y \to Z$ measurable, if we equip $X \times Y$ with a product sigma algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ need not be measurable. Let $E$ be a non-measurable subset of the reals, and define $f$ by
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $x=y$ and $x\in E$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Essentially we're placing $E$ along the diagonal $y=x$ and $f$ is the indicator function of the diagonal version (call it $E'$) of $E$. Clearly every slice $f(x,\cdot)$ and $f(\cdot,y)$ is measurable, but $f^{-1}(\{1\})$ equals $E'$, which is not measurable.